# oracle 11g exp hangs

Tags: oracle, export, schema

When trying to export a schema from an `Oracle 11g` database, with the following command

```
exp userid=EA/@ASID file=c:\m\ea.dmp
```

it starts exporting quite some tables before it gets stuck eternally:

```
...
EXP-00091: Fragliche Statistiken werden exportiert.
. . Export der Tabelle                T_SCENARIOTYPES          3 Zeilen exportiert
EXP-00091: Fragliche Statistiken werden exportiert.
. . Export der Tabelle                 T_SECUSERGROUP          6 Zeilen exportiert
. . Export der Tabelle            T_SECUSERPERMISSION          2 Zeilen exportiert
. . Export der Tabelle    

             T_SNAPSHOT
```

The schema is useable and the table `T_SNAPSHOT` is accessible and shows (at first glance) reasonable content in SQL Developer

Any ideas? Thx in advance!

Comment: How many rows are in `t_snapshot`? Is the size of the dump file still increasing after it seems to have hung? Is anything going to the log that isn't going to screen?

Comment: Meanwhile I added ´FEEDBACK=10 to the commandline and found that the data is dumped and the process is NOT hanging. It just takes hours, which I did not expect.

Answer (score 2):

> The `EXP-00091 Exporting questionable statistics` error happens when you export table data with its related optimizer statistics, and Oracle cannot verify the currency of these statistics. When CBO statistics are created/updated with dbms_stats, the time is noted, but it's always a good idea not to export statistics since they should be
>   recalculated after import.
>
> You can remove the EXP-00091 error by exporting with `statistics="none"` or by setting the client character set (e.g. `export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1`).

[source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_exp_00091_exporting_questionable_statistics.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out. Meanwhile my problem vanished